# Reading CSV with comma at last line

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i'm using Python to read in a series of CSVs that were obtained via a web scraper (there's thousands so editing by hand is a no go). The data looks like this:

```
"Client: Secret Client"
"G/L Account: (#-#-#) Secret Type of Account"
"Process Date: MM/DD/YYYY"
"Export Date: MM/DD/YYYY"
"Unit Name ","Description","Pay. Type ","Amount","Tran. Date "
"last, first","some note (dates with commas like 17 Aug, 2018 could be here)","Credit Card ","$AMNT.CHANGE","Date and Timestamp"
"Total","","","$AMNT.CHANGE","
```

If you count carefully you'll see a final comma followed by a rogue ". The code I'm trying to use is here:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv

def read_temp(file):
    tmp = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, error_bad_lines=False, quotechar='"', skiprows=5, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,skipinitialspace=True, skipfooter=1)
    gl = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, error_bad_lines=False, quotechar='"', skiprows=1, nrows=1, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,skipinitialspace=True)
    proc_date = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, error_bad_lines=False, quotechar='"', skiprows=2, nrows=1, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,skipinitialspace=True)
    cols = ['NAME', 'DESCRIPTION', 'PAY_TYP', 'AMOUNT', 'TRAN_DATE']
    tmp.columns = cols
    # print(tmp.columns)
    # print(file)
    tmp['G/L_ACCOUNT'] = gl[0][0].split(':')[1]
    tmp['PROCESS_DATE'] = proc_date[0][0].split(':')[1]
    for col in tmp.columns:
        tmp[col] = tmp[col].str.strip('"')
    return tmp
master = "C:\\path\\to\\master\\"
want=[]
flag = 0
for direc in os.listdir(master):
    for file in os.listdir(master+direc):
        temp = read_temp(master+direc+'\\'+file)
        want.append(temp)

df = pd.concat(want)
```

the error is:

```
',' expected after '"'
```

I think if I could use a CSV Reader and regular expressions (which I have zero experience with) to read each line before hand and find everything that's surrounded by " " then I could change it somehow or posisbly delete that ending comma and double quote.
Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Still new to utilizing stackoverflow - who and why downvoated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test with the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) module does not fail

```
import csv

data = """"Client: Secret Client"
"G/L Account: (#-#-#) Secret Type of Account"
"Process Date: MM/DD/YYYY"
"Export Date: MM/DD/YYYY"
"Unit Name ","Description","Pay. Type ","Amount","Tran. Date "
"last, first","some note (dates with commas like 17 Aug, 2018 could be here)","Credit Card ","$AMNT.CHANGE","Date and Timestamp"
"Total","","","$AMNT.CHANGE","
"""

reader = csv.reader(data.split("\n"), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    print(', '.join(row))
```

but also get "confused" by the last, incomplete element:

```
Client: Secret Client
G/L Account: (#-#-#) Secret Type of Account
Process Date: MM/DD/YYYY
Export Date: MM/DD/YYYY
Unit Name , Description, Pay. Type , Amount, Tran. Date 
last, first, some note (dates with commas like 17 Aug, 2018 could be here), Credit Card , $AMNT.CHANGE, Date and Timestamp
Total, , , $AMNT.CHANGE,
```

But you could just remove the offending characters from your data, e.g. with [`rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) and "[slicing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html)":

```
pos = data.rfind(',"', -5)
if pos != -1:
    data = data.strip()[:pos]
print( data[-15:] )
```

should print `,"$AMNT.CHANGE"`. 
It searches for `,"` on the last 5 characters of the string. If it is found, the position is returned, which is used to remove the respective characters (or rather, return a string without them).

The `strip()` is just to remove any newline (introduced by embedding your data with a string literal """).

Alternatively, if the problem is *always* those two extra characters, you could *slice* them off by providing a negative slice index, e.g. `data[:-2]`

No real need for a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html), however

```
import re
data = re.sub(",\"?$", "", data, 1)
```

would do the trick, and it also works in case there is just a trailing `,`.
You can [play with this on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iNECJY/1) which also explains what the expression does.

Now pandas should not have any trouble parsing the data.

Comment: This looks like it'll be perfect. The problem is always the last 2 characters so the slicing should work - I just wasn't sure how to implement that with the pd.read_csv(), so the small automated preprocessing before reading it in is super useful. Thank you!